# Fraud Ring Detection using H2O driverless AI - samples, pointers needed

Tags: neo4j, driverless-ai

I am very curious to know how H2O can help in Fraud Ring Detection. I am referring to Venkatesh Reamanthan's video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9S3xchrzlY)  where he talks about fraud ring detection and wanted to know if there are any samples published by H2O.

We all know that, if we know a fraud scenario, we can easily construct a Neo4J Cipher query to detect fraud rings. I am not able to understand how a graph db can be fed to a ML model and when a new transaction happens how ML model can predict if the parties in the transaction are part of a fraud ring or not?

My understanding is the below after going through the video : If we have a graphdb, if I somehow export this to an edgelist and feed to Node2Vec to produce a word2vec model, and then feed the output / dataset extracted out of this word2vec model to H2O driverless AI for further training. Is my understanding correct? Are there any samples to do it?

At this point, I am clue less as to how to convert Node2Vec's output in to a format that h2o driverless AI can understand and how can it actually predict a fraud ring.

Any help, pointers, ideas appreciated.

Comment: the video you are referencing is using Driverless AI one of the products  of H2O.ai the company. The tag you specified for this post is `h2o` which refers to h2o-3 H2O.ai's open source platform. Can you clarify whether you are feeding your data to a H2O-3 model or a Driverless AI model, by updating the title and the question content. Note both of these products expect that a dataset, not model, will be fed to them.

Comment: @Lauren made the edits as suggested by you.

Comment: driverless-ai expects tabular data, you can see the list of expected data formats here: http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/release_notes.html

Comment: @SRK Have you found any relevant lectures/examples with graph db and H2o since you asked? :)